# VBA Excel: Application.DisplayAlerts not working if called from another macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I've got a macro opening another workbook that can be readonly. To avoid readonly alerts I switch Application.DisplayAlerts propery to False, like this

```
Sub tmp()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Debug.Print Application.DisplayAlerts
Workbooks.Open "\\Co-file01\FileName.xlsx"
End Sub
```

And it works fine, but if I call it from another macro, like this

```
Sub tmp1()
Application.Run "tmp"
End Sub
```

I still get the alert, and the code stops working, waiting for response. The line

```
Debug.Print Application.DisplayAlerts
```

returns False, so it seems the property is really switched, but for some reason it does'not apply.

Can anyone explain the reasons it works this way and suggest any workaround?

I'm working with Excel 2016 64bit, Windows 7 if matters

Comment: You should call the macro directly by its name: simply type tmp1 on a new line, rather than using application.run

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

jkpieterse suggested the answer

> You should call the macro directly by its name: simply type tmp1 on a
>   new line, rather than using application.run